# Pericom serial port driver for CentOS / Red Hat 7.8 (proper baud_base)

Tags: linux, serial-port, driver, centos7, uart

I need to port the serial driver shipped with CentOS 8.2 to CentOS 7.8 and, if possible, improve* it a bit (unless that isn't the only solution).

The hardware is a CompactPCIe computer, which consists of:

- CPU card + side card SCZ-NVM (2 x RS-232, Serial controller: Pericom Semiconductor Device 7954, Subsystem: Pericom Semiconductor Device 7954)
- peripheral card SU2-BALLAD (4 x RS-232, Serial controller: Pericom Semiconductor Device 7954, Subsystem: EKF Elektronik GmbH Device e224)

In CentOS 7.8 none of the 6 serial ports work; in CentOS 8.2 all serial ports work fine*, so I guess the driver shipped with CentOS 7.8 is incorrect.
The cause of the problem is incorrect "baud_base" parameter (115200) and a temporary solution is to set it to 921600 (using setserial).

*Serial port drivers provided with CentOS 7.8/8.2 have a common, not very significant drawback:

- they detect twice as many serial ports than the existing ones (4 instead of 2 and 8 instead of 4).

It would be great to have a driver that sets the correct "baud_base" and detects the correct number of serial ports.

Where in the kernel source code can I find the part responsible for setting "baud_base" for the hardware mentioned above?
(and the part responsible for detecting numer of serial ports, but it isn't crucial)
Will it end up compiling kernel module or compiling entire kernel?

```
lspci -vvv

08:00.0 Serial controller: Pericom Semiconductor Device 7954 (prog-if 02 [16550])
    Subsystem: EKF Elektronik GmbH Device e224
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 19
    Region 0: I/O ports at a000 [size=64]
    Region 1: Memory at d1100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=375mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [9c] Vital Product Data
        Not readable
    Capabilities: [a4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=28 <?>
    Capabilities: [e0] Express (v1) Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <64ns, L1 <1us
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq+ AuxPwr+ TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <1us
            ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp-
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk-
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk- DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES- TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap- CGenEn- ChkCap- ChkEn-
    Kernel driver in use: serial

09:00.0 Serial controller: Pericom Semiconductor Device 7954 (prog-if 02 [16550])
    Subsystem: Pericom Semiconductor Device 7954
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 18
    Region 0: I/O ports at 9000 [size=64]
    Region 1: Memory at d1000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=375mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [9c] Vital Product Data
        Not readable
    Capabilities: [a4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=28 <?>
    Capabilities: [e0] Express (v1) Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <64ns, L1 <1us
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq+ AuxPwr+ TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <1us
            ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp-
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES- TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap- CGenEn- ChkCap- ChkEn-
    Kernel driver in use: serial
```

Answer (score 0):

In the 3.10 kernel, baud_table is in drivers/tty/tty_ioctl.c.  You'll note it supports 921600 Hz.   https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10/source/drivers/tty/tty_ioctl.c#L263

In the later 4.12 kernel, a new file tty_baudrate.c is added.  This file appears to be backported to CentOS 7.